# How do I reference a conference paper that is due to be published later this year

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am writing a paper that builds on a previous work. The previous work has been accepted at a conference and will be published as part of the proceedings, but it hasn't been published yet. Do I just reference it using the standard format for referencing unpublished works or not?

Comment: Interesting question - with a journal article usually it's either "in review", "in press" (very brief these days) or out there... but with a conference paper that's accepted and waiting for the proceedings to come out... I'm curious as to the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Either "Accepted for Intl. Conf. on Whatever, 2018", or 
"To appear in Proc. Intl. Conf. on Whatever, 2018", or
"Intl. Conf. on Whatever, 2018, to appear".